# How to make a 100% Stacekd chart with multiple columns?

Tags: graph, bar-chart, spotfire, stacked-chart

I want to make a chart with multiple columns
I have four columns made of "O" and "X" and want to make a chart that shows what percentage of each column is "O" and "X"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4nSm.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD7JU.jpg)

So, each name of the column should go to X-axis of the chart and the bar chart should show the percentage of "O" and "X"
but I can't get all the data in one chart. I don't Know how to set X and Y-axis and the data that goes in. Does it need coding or other settings or changes to table(data)?
I am stuck please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlofT.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by unpivoting the table.

Either unpivot the original table,
or create a second table (+ > Other > then select the original table from *Linked copy to data in analysis*) and
unpivot that one.

In the data canvas, click on the + to the right of the table and select *Add transformations* > *Unpivot*.
Select all your four columns to go into *Columns to transform*.

You know have a data table with columns [Category], containing your initial four columns, and [Value] containing the Os and Xs (and any empty values).

To get the bar chart, select Category on the X axis, Count([Value]) on the Y axis, and colour by [Value]. In *Properties > Appearance* select *100% stacked bars*.

Note that the empty values will not be counted, unless you create another transformation on the data canvas to calculate and replace [Value]
with a place-holder if it is empty, something like this:

```
case  when [Value] is null then 'empty' else [Value] end
```